# What version of Windows can I install on a 2009 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp, windows

I would like to convert my old 2009 MacBook Pro into a Windows machine to use some apps that don’t run or do so extremely poorly on macOS.

This MBP supports El Capitan (10.11) as its last version.
What version of Windows can I install on it using Bootcamp?

Thank you very much

Comment: I am running Windows 10 on a 2006 [MacbookPro2,1](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.16-15-specs.html).  This model will not boot Windows installer from USB so I removed the disk and installed Windows via PC and then put the disk back.  It works fine - only the X1600 display driver was hard to find (I used XP version).  If you can boot from USB you can see  [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322269/can-i-install-win-10-gpt-formatted-usb-installer-on-macbook-pro-without-using?rq=1).  Windows is very forgiving - you could try it.

Comment: Thanks! I plan to install the free version of Windows 10. Should I download the 32 or 64 bit one for the 2009 MBP?

Comment: Install 64bit.  You'll not find 32bit bootcamp drivers.  Use the latest ones for your model - doesn't matter if it says Windows 7 - they will probably work if you unzip and apply them through device manager.  The main thing I needed from bootcamp was trackpad driver for right click - Windows update got almost all the others so if you have a USB mouse to use while installing it will help.

Comment: @NotationMaster, which model is your 2009 MBP? Apple Menu > About this Mac > Overview > System Report > Hardware, under Hardware Overview there is a Model Identifier. It will say something like MacBookPro6,1 or MacBookPro5,2 or somesuch. What is the model identifier of yours?

Comment: It’s the 15” mid-2009 model, don’t have it near right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that Mac will only support Windows 7

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016

Even your model does not look like it supports Windows 8

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457

And Windows 7 is End of Life in mid January. It will still work but no more security (or other) updates after that. So it's do-able but not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very good possibility you can install Windows 10. I have installed Windows 10 on both a 2007 and a 2011 iMac computers even though Apple does not officially support Windows 10 on either computer.

The easiest method of installing would be to use the optical (DVD) drive. If you have the [latest ISO release of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), then you will need a dual layer DVD (DL) to burn the image to.

If you do not have a working DVD drive, the you can use this [complex method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521) to install.

I should also warn that one of the Boot Camp Support Software files may need to be replaced if you install the latest Window 10. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362637/wdf-violation-blue-screen-after-upgrading-mac-to-windows-10-may-2019-update-190) for more information.

Comment: It seems that such method is for bootcamp. I want only Windows on that machine.

Comment: Does your DVD work?

Comment: Sometimes it fails to eject the disc but otherwise it should.

Comment: You state in you comments that you "plan to install the free version of Windows 10". Where do you get a free version. I know you can download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), but this is not free.

Comment: If your DVD drive did not work, then you could use OS X to install Windows 10. Next remove OS X. Finally, expand Windows to use the entire drive. The procedure for this is very complex and should only be used as a last resort. In your case, you would be better off burning a DVD.

Comment: I knew one could use the free version of Windows 10 with all its limitations if one wanted but if this is not true I may be better off selling this Mac and getting a basic Windows laptop for a little more :-)

Comment: There are [articles](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-get-windows-10-for-free/) that explain how to get Windows 10 for free. However, I do believe if you download and install Windows 10 on a machine that has never run Windows  before, then eventually you will need to buy a license. You do not need a license to try Windows 10 to see how it performs, but eventually you will be required to activate Windows. To active, you may need to buy a license, if no other free method works.