# What's the best way to replace MacOS with Windows & Linux Dual boot?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, dual-boot

I have had it with macOS.

I use a 2014 MacBook Air.

To use some apps I need, I had to upgrade to the newest macOS, but this slowed the computer down like crazy.
Otherwise, I stay with an older version of OS X (Yosemite) which doesn't lag, but is not supported by many apps.

Right now I just have macOS. I want to get rid of it and use Windows & Ubuntu.

So how do I remove mac OS and dual boot Windows and Ubuntu on this thing?

Comment: Which apps that you need from OS X that you think Ubuntu would provided, but Windows would not?

Comment: You are simply expecting too much out of a 7-year-old Macbook Air, which was never designed to do heavy lifting anyways. Of course the newest OS would render it slow, but the same problem would happen with a Windows laptop.

Comment: [Remove macOS and Install Windows 10 Only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306558/remove-macos-and-install-windows-10-only). Then install Ubuntu and try and get both to dual boot.

Comment: I agree with @FeliniusRex comment - have just put a new battery in a 2012 macbook air for my daughter, works well for homework, netflix and youtube. And she does not do CFD or heavy rendering etc so it’s fine.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Nothing really. A lot of apps I need are available on OSX/Windows but not ubuntu. So I'd like to use Ubuntu but have the option to boot into Windows. I just don't want to use OSX anymore.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I know it's complicated to do this. Most apps that I use run fine on this kind of hardware if it was windows or linux.

Comment: @piranhas I'm noting that you've specified the version of MacOs under discussion, but not the version of Windows. Then you make a claim that MacOS Big Sur will not run well on the hardware but that Windows (no version specified) will. I am leaving the discussion at that observation.

Comment: I would assume the OP would install the current Windows 10. Windows 7 is now obsolete and Windows 8-8.1 are junk. However, I installed Windows 7 on a 2018 mac mini back in February and was able to upgrade to Windows 10 for free.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave Windows as is and replace macOS with Ubuntu. There will be a conflict between the files in the EFI partition for Windows and the files the Ubuntu installer will place in this partition. One way to avoid this conflict would be to create a second EFI partition when installing Ubuntu. After the installation completes, move the Ubuntu boot files to this new EFI partition.

Comment: I actualy only have macOS at the moment and would like to switch to Ubuntu+Windows. Would you recommend a certain order of doing things? eg. windows first or ubuntu first?

Comment: 1) Use the Boot Camp Assistant to create an USB Windows 10 installer. 2) Install Windows 10 by erasing macOS and leaving space for Ubuntu. 3) Create an USB Ubuntu installer. 4) Install Ubuntu. Add a second EFI partition and an partition for Ubuntu. The swap partition is optional. 5) Move the Grub boot files from the first EFI partition to the second EFI partition. 6) Replace the Windows boot file in the first EFI partition that was overwritten by the Ubuntu installation.